# Firefox and Windows Media Player: small green horizontal line after a while

Tags: firefox, windows-media-player, wmv

we use the Windows Media Player plugin to play some video pages on firefox 20. This works great, but after a while (this differs, but often after round about 30 minutes) the videos will be not longer shown and instead of the video only a small horiziontal green line in the middle of the video area is shown (on black background). The video files are ok because the same files will be played successfull before the green line is shown. And after restarting firefox all is still fine until after several minutes the green line is shown again ...

I have already installed the latest graphic driver. Also dis-/enabling Video Acceleration in Windows Media Player don't helps.

Here our environment:

- Win7 64b
- WMP 12.0.7601.17514
- Firefox 20.0.1
- Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin 1.0.0.8

**EDIT:**

I can see that the Media Player creates for each played video a own playlist. In the status bar of the WMP plugin stands "Wiedergabeliste1", Wiedergabeliste2", "Wiedergabeliste3", ... ("Wiedergabeliste" means "playlist") for the first, second, third, ... video. But with the first video which is displayed as a green line on the status bar stands only the name of the video file (without ".wmv").

Also if the videos are showing correct the "Statistic" (right mouse click into the WMP plugin) shows me valid values for frame rate and so on. But if only the green line was shown the frame rate and some other values are "0".

I have also tested this with Firefox 22 with the same effect (green line after some minutes). On IE 8 the effect is a little bit different. After some minutes I get then green line too, but only for each second video (one video is ok, next video a green line, next video ok again, next video a green line , ...)

Thanks and regards,
Steffen

PS: This is also posted on: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-media-player-small-green-horizontal-line/c9ea0621-a678-4017-9aac-55a1239db632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this problem is related to the Hardware. We have found out that the green line occurres only on one Hardware and on at least three other Hardware machines not. But it seems it's not related to the graphic card (Intel/ATI HD4000) because we have not seen this problem on a other machine with the same CPU and graphic card ...